# SQL join between 3 tables, get the unmatched entities

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
BATCH
facName lotName

LOT
lotName facID

FAC
ID facName
```

The **LOT** table holds lots, each lot is related to fac, by ID (`LOT.facID=FAC.ID`).
  The **BATCH** table holds pairs of facName and lotName. Those pairs are not necessarily correct, means that it can contain `facName` and `lotName` that doesn't relate to each other (by the **LOT** table).I want to get the wrong records.

For example, for this data:

```
BATCH
facName lotName
fac1    lot1
fac1    lot2

LOT
lotName facID
lot1    1
lot2    2

FAC
ID      facName
1       fac1
2       fac2
```

I want to get

```
BATCH
facName lotName
fac1    lot2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you recognize that `fac1` does not relate to `lot2`?

Comment: By the 'LOT' table. lot2 has facID '2' (and not '1')

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a `JOIN`

```
select facName, lotName
from batch b
join fac f on b.facName = f.facName
join lot l on b.lotName = l.lotName
where f.id != l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle I would do something like this: 
I think you can do this also on MySQL:

```
select *
from batch
where not exists ( select 1 from LOT 
      join FAC on FAC.id = LOT.facid 
      where FAC.facname = BATCH.facname 
      and LOT.lotname = BATCH.lotname)
```